# Vertically aligning Angular component within index.html - Using display:grid

Tags: html, css, angular

Is there an easy way in which I can vertically align my Angular component do be displayed?

I am using `display: grid` for the main container.

**[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-clock-app)**

**clock.component.html**

```
<div class="container">
  {{time | date: 'HH:mm:ss'}}
</div>
```

**clock.component.css**

```
:host {
  margin: auto;
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="container">
  <app-clock></app-clock>
</div>
```

**app.component.css**

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you would prefer a `flexbox` solution, but this is what I've started to use recently in such cases:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%; /* make sure .containers's parents also have fixed height */
}

:host {
    display: inline-block;
    flex: 1;
}
```

Also, there is a positioning approach, it's pretty common in your case:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}

:host {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: Ah! I forgot about the position: absolute solution! Thanks for reminding me :-)